# The expand and close icons will always appear automatically in group column,although I didn't set columnGroupShow

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

> If a group has any child that is dependent on the open / closed state, the open / close icon will appear. Otherwise the icon will not be shown.

This is the description of the official document,But that is not true, when I have more than three levels of grouping columns, the expand and close icons will always appear automatically,I confirm that I have no children dependent on open and closed states.

This is my example: https://plnkr.co/edit/dGxKxiSpuftjQEh9

```js
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: 'country',
          colId: 'country',
          children: [
            {
              field: 'total',
              colId: 'total',
            },
            {
              field: 'gold',
              colId: 'gold',
              children: [
                {
                  field: 'year',
                  colId: 'year',
                },
                {
                  field: 'silver',
                  colId: 'silver',
                  children: [
                    {
                      field: 'bronze',
                      colId: 'bronze',
                    },
                    {
                      field: 'date',
                      colId: 'date',
                      // children: [
                      //   {
                      //     field: 'total',
                      //     colId: 'total',
                      //   },
                      // ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
```

[image: example]

Comment: its a bug since you will not get expand/collapse button if drill-down level is less than 3. a workaround for this would be to define expand/collapse icon which will render nothing since expanding collapsing that button doesn't do anything anyways.

Comment: Yes,I have hidden the icon because I don’t need it.